# Frobenius on projective variety is not an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

This is exercise 1.8 from *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves (Silverman)*. Part 3 confuses me because isn't $\phi$ the identity, thus an isomorphism?

> Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and let $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a variety defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$.
>
> 1. Prove that the $q$th-power map $\phi = [X_0^q,\ldots,X_n^q]$ is a morphism $\phi : V \rightarrow V$. It is called the Frobenius
>      morphism.
> 2. Prove that $\phi$ is one-to-one and onto.
> 3. Prove that $\phi$ is not an isomorphism.
> 4. Prove that $V(\mathbb{F}_q) = \{P \in V : \phi(P) = P\}$.

Comment: The fourth statement tells you that $\phi$ is the identity precisely on the $\Bbb{F}_q$-valued points of $V$. This suggests it isn't the identity on _all_ points of $V$. What is your definition of $\Bbb{P}^n$?

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! $\mathbb{P}^n$ uses an algebraic closure, I forgot that.

Comment: Notice that when you have a morphism explicitly given in coordinates you can compute the Jacobian to see what the induced map on tangent spaces is. In this case it is the zero map because of the characteristic! An isomorphism must induce an isomorphism on tangent spaces as well. In other words, the Frobenius morphism is singular everywhere.

Comment: @Matt this works if we know the variety $V$ has at least one non-singular point... Is that automatic?